# Javascript confirm() method. How to put separate action on 'cancel' and 'ok' button

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page where I have put a JS code for confirm() method. I am calling this from the form "onsubmit". The dialog box has 2 buttons "OK' and 'cancel'. On clicking "OK" the form should be submitted which is happening but on click of 'cancel' button I need to redirect the page to some other page. Below is the JS code.

```
function showDialog() {
    if(confirm("Press OK to confirm")) {
     console.log("Clicked OK, confirmation.");} else {
console.log("Clicked Cancel, confirmation.");
```

}

Below is the form tag where I am calling JS function:

```
<form:form  name="login" id="login" action="<%=loginPass%>" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onsubmit= "showDialog()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default onsubmit functionality if you ´return false;´ there.
Then you pass the form to your function and call ´.submit()´ there or redirect the user using ´location.href´.

```
 function showDialog(form) { if(confirm("Press OK to confirm")) { console.log("Clicked OK, confirmation.");
form.submit();
} else { console.log("Clicked Cancel, confirmation."); 
location.href = "https://whereyouwantto.go";
}



<form:form name="login" id="login" action="<%=loginPass%>" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onsubmit= "showDialog(this);return false;">
```

Comment: sorry for the bad format. I am on my phone right now

Comment: Hi Sebastian! Thanks for the reply. I am trying to redirect to a different JSP page. How can we achieve this from JS function?

Comment: As long as your site has a URL, where it can be found the file-format doesn't matter